# LINQ Query to filter results using where and lambda expression is returning wrong results

Tags: linq, filter, lambda

Filtering an `IEnumerable` result set using a `where` clause with condition is returning duplicate entries.

This is the query we are using to filter results. `links` is an `IEnumerable` with count 299. When the below query is executed, `validLinks` count is coming to 588, and each entry is duplicated. Please help us determine what is wrong with this query.

```
var validLinks = links.Where(link => link.Categories
                                         .Where(category => category.!IsCatchAll)
                                         .Any());
```

Comment: The implementation of `Where` can never expand the number of items in an `IEnumerable`.  If the counts are correct then either the lambda in the `Where` or some other code` is expanding the underlying collection.

Answer (score 3):

That code won't compile because the  `!` is in the wrong place. Also you don't need to do `Where` and `Any`. Try this:

```
var validLinks = links.Where(link => link.Categories.Any(category => !category.IsCatchAll);
```

Comment: Sorry.That's a type mistake in syntax. Your response(p.s.w.g) is correct and has given 299 results. Thanks. However, some more code is executed after this method and is again giving duplicates. It's a CAML query. 'll need to check that!!